# Create a soundboard with differents audios (more than 1)

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Hey I want to create a soundboard but I don't know how to put more audios.

I want them when you click on it start and if you reclick it stop and if you click again it start from the beginning (look the script).

I don't know how I can add more audios and use the same script. (I create new audio I change the id but in the script the id stay audio1 so it doesn't work).

Thanks

```
<audio id="audio1" src="myaudio.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="play()">Play</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function play() {
var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
}else{
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0
}
}
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use multiple audios: You can pass a value to the function to determine which audio you want to play.

```
<audio id="audio1" src="myaudio1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="audio2" src="myaudio2.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="audio3" src="myaudio3.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="play(1)">Play 1</button>
<button onClick="play(2)">Play 2</button>
<button onClick="play(3)">Play 3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function play(e) {
var audio = document.getElementById('audio'+e);

var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].pause();

audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
}
</script>`
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
function play(e) {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio'+e);

    var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    var shouldPlay = true;
    for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) {
        if(sounds[i].currentTime > 0 && !sounds[i].paused && !sounds[i].ended) {
            sounds[i].pause();
            sounds[i].currentTime = 0;

            if(audio == sounds[i]) shouldPlay = false;
        }
    }


    if(shouldPlay) {
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked the, songs are playing but when I reclick on "Play 1" the song restart at the beginning. What do I need to change to stop the song and not restart from the beginning ?

Comment: Hmm... what happens when you try to remove the `audio.currentTime = 0` line?

Comment: When I start song 1 and I reclick it doesn't stop, but when I click song 2 it start and pause song 1, so if I reclick song 1 it continue where it stops when I clicked song 2

Comment: I've added a new version to my post. Does it work for you?